# Issue in associating a specific role using a customised spree controller's view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, view, controller, spree

I am new to spree. I created a customised controller client(not created it's model). The controller and and all the corresponding views I created were with the help of pre-existing user controller & views created by Spree. In the 'new' view there I render a form to create a new user.

Now when **I select a role for the user(both while creating and updating) it automatically selects the role id as 1.** But same form works fine in 'user' section.
Related codes :

inside client model:

```
module Spree
  module Admin
    class ClientsController < ResourceController   
     .
      # Client does not have its own model
     .
      def new
          @user = Spree.user_class.new    
      end
      def edit
         @roles = Spree::Role.all
         @user =Spree.user_class.find_by(id: params[:id])
         user = @user
      end

      def update
          @user = Spree.user_class.find_by(id: params[:id]) #added to remove null class error
        if params[:user][:password].blank? && params[:user][:password_confirmation].blank?
          params[:user].delete(:password)
          params[:user].delete(:password_confirmation)
        end

        if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
          set_roles
          flash.now[:success] = Spree.t(:account_updated)
        end

        render :edit
      end
       .
       .
       .
end
```

No matter which role I choose for the user it role sends the first id.

While this code works perfectly fine for already existing Spree User.

Please see to my query. It would be a great help. Thank you. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Where are you selecting the role ? Can you share that piece of code as well ?

Comment: `<% @roles.each do |role| %>
        <div class="checkbox">
          <% if role.name == 'client' %>
          <%= label_tag "client_spree_role_#{role.name}" do %>
            <%= check_box_tag 'client[spree_role_ids][]', role.name, @user.spree_roles.include?(role), :id => "clients_spree_role_#{role.name}" %>
            <%= role.name %>
             <% end %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      <% end %>`

Comment: Can you please edit the OP with the code you have added as comment, it's hard to read it, if you put all this code in here. Thank you!

Comment: `But same form works fine in 'user' section` where is this ? What form are you referring to ? Can you update the OP with the form ?

Comment: `<% @roles.each do |role| %>`
        `<div class="checkbox">`
                `<% if role.name == 'clinic' %>`
                    `<%= label_tag "clinic_spree_role_#{role.name}" do %>`
                             `<%= check_box_tag 'clinic[spree_role_ids][]', role.name, @user.spree_roles.include?(role), :id => "clinics_spree_role_#{role.name}" %>`
                                    `<%= role.name %>`
                             `<% end %>`
                `<% end %>`
        `</div>`
`<% end %>`

Comment: Actually spree has created it's own user section. Using those controllers and views I am trying to create a customised section 'client' . Sorry for the bad editting I hope you can relate to it. Pardon please. @KedarnagMukanahallipatna

Comment: No Issues. However, you'll have to ask questions in a manner that is suitable for others to read. So I suggest, you delete the comments and add them in the OP. Back to the question, can you also share the view (which should contain a form) would give a clearer picture.